# Azure APIM: How to change backend URI

Tags: azure, url, url-rewriting, azure-api-management, apim

I have defined an API in Azure APIM.  I have added one method /users.  I want that method to be translated in the backend service as /createUsers.

So frontend API: POST https://xxx.domain.com/abc/dev/service/users ->
https://yyy.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/createUsers

However I am always getting backend api as https://yyy.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/createUsers/users.  Is there a way to fix this issue?

I have tried to check the override check box in Backend but still getting /users appended at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've defined your API's service URL as "https://yyy.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/createUsers", in that case you need to rewrite operation URI portion to "/" with `rewrite-uri` policy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL):

```
<rewrite-uri template="/" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```